# jQuery scrollTop Not Triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, scrolltop, scrollto

I have some markup like so:

```
<div id="landing">
    <p>Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin.</p>
</div>

<header id="header">
    <p>Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin.</p>
    <p>Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin.</p>
    <p>Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin.</p>
</header>
```

And I'm trying to get it so that, when the `<p>` element in `#landing` is clicked, jQuery scrolls the page down to the `#header` element.

Going by the jQuery docs, I would have assumed it would be as simple as:

```
$('#landing p').click(function() {
    $('#header').scrollTop(250);
});
```

But that doesn't appear to work at all. Plus, every other thread I look at (including some answers to my previous / similar threads) that uses the `scrollTop` method seems to use more complex code. So then I thought maybe I need to have something like this:

```
$('#landing p').bind('click', function(e) {
    try {
        e.preventDefault();
        target = this.hash;
        $('#header').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 150);
    } catch (error) {
        alert('error - ' + error);
    }
});
```

Yet that doesn't work either. I get no error messages in the console but the event just won't seem to trigger. I've tested it with a simple alert statement which works fine, just I can't get it to scroll

Comment: can you please make a fiddle for that, so that we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something like this?

```
$('#landing p').click(function(){
    var headerOffset=$('#header').offset();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop:headerOffset.top
    });
});
```

Comment: that works perfectly thank you :D strange how the jQuery docs don't mention anything about it working like this! At least not that I've noticed anyway